# Book about a girl who goes to a kingdom and makes a fake friend who is turned old and imprisoned

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m looking for a book I read in high school that I very vaguely remember.

The things I do know are that a girl goes to a kingdom and there is another girl that makes fake friends with her. They wear gems and jewelry to enhance their beauty. The fake friend somehow gets turned old and gets thrown into a dungeon where the main character goes to visit her every so often.

I know that it’s a long shot but honestly, anything helps!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  We don't know when you were in highschool.  Do you recall the cover of the book?